# 2 Windows servers, 2 web sites, 1 external IP

Tags: iis, web-server, web-hosting

I have one external IP. I need to host two websites www.domain1.com and www.domain2.com on two different servers. I'm using IIS.

How can I do that?

Comment: `How can I do that?` - http://viewrz.com/video/google-it - seriously, you can find info on how to do this easily.  If you run into issues while implementing it, that's different and on-topic.

Comment: @ thecleaner - yeah, right! Once you know the answer Goggling it is easy :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On one of your servers you set up [IIS Application Request Routing (ARR)](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/application-request-routing), which listens on the external IP. On the same server you have your first site listing on an internal IP.

On the second server you have your second site listing on another internal IP.

You set up ARR which is a reverse proxy to forward the requests to the correct site based on host headers.

Both DNS entries point to the same single external address.